# Saving data in NSDictionary from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary

Here is my JSON format data which I have parsed and save in A dictionary called NSDictionary *dic.I have an other NSDicitonary named dic1 in which I just want to store data from //1 to //3 how can i do that ?please Help ?

```
//0
[{
    "about": "Mother, actor, entrepreneur, fitness enthusiast and an eternal positive thinker",
    "id": "238bb4ca-606d-4817-afad-78bee2898264",
    "username": "Shilpa shetty kundr"
}
//1
, {
    "about": "Www.Nargisfakhri.com Instagram- @NargisFakhri Twitter- @NargisFakhri FaceBook- Nargis Fakhri ",
    "id": "cda99c24-955a-4c58-a6a8-c811938df530",
    "username": "Nargis Fakhri"
}
//2
, {
    "description": "Celebrating Black Friday in this lovely black cut out romper and floral accessories. I love black and i think it is the easiest thing to wear when i am in doubt. So a black romper solves my dilemma of what to wear when i am short of time to decide and outfit. When you wear black add some fun accessories to keep the outfit fun and lively.",
    "id": "fa6d9bdf-eae3-4d6c-a668-9be94cfaf980",
    "verb": "created this story on 25 October"
},
//3
 {
    "description": "Today's outfit! #ootd Sheer shirts are always so sexy. Team it up with a bustier inside and it looks elegant and sexy at the same time. I wore my purple sheer shirt with an embellished maxi skirt and statement necklace. Sheer shirts looks fabulous with statement necklaces or layered chains.",
    "id": "066f2bac-1fa8-44f8-b2b6-780df3324c71",
    "verb": "created this story on 21 October"
}]
```

This is How i have done.?

```
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id allKeys = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

userIDArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<[allKeys count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *arrayResult = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
    if([arrayResult objectForKey:@"id"]!=NULL){
        NSString *id=[arrayResult objectForKey:@"id"];
        [userIDArray addObject:id];

    }
 }
```

My point is in allKeys whole data is saved instead of saving whole data from //0 to //3 i just need data from //02 to //03 stored in some Dictionary.

Comment: That's an array, not a dictionary

Comment: @dan sir is there any solluttion for it ?

Comment: It's unclear what you actually wish to do. You should update your question with some relevant code. Show what dictionaries you have and how you wish to take data from one and put it in the other.

Comment: @HarshitGoel: What about writing code? Go through the NSArray and NSMutableArray documentation and see what methods are there.

Comment: @gnasher729 Sir please have a look on updation. I have edited the material.

Comment: What happens after the loop when you NSLog the `userIDArray`?

Comment: @danh can u help me in this one help ?

Comment: @rmaddy sir need Help for this one ?

Comment: What help do you seek?  Is the answer you marked correct not the answer?

Comment: I just rolled back your latest changes to your question. You already accepted an answer to your question. Do not completely change the question. If you have a new question, please post a new question.

Comment: @rmaddy sir next time i wiil keep taht in mind but can u help on this one

Comment: @danh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674494/clicking-on-like-all-the-view-should-show-like-ojective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you realize this is array:

```
    NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *a1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 1; i < a.count; i++) {
       [a1 addObject: a[i]];
    }
```

Comment: Or [subarrayWithRange] is more neat