# Clicking on Like all the view should show like objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsuserdefaults, nsnotificationcenter

When I select **Throwback** -> **Description** occurs if I click on **like** button the like button changes to **unlike** and " like count=1099" increases. If I press back I want this **unlike** to be displayed next to **Throwback** let say in a label and again select **Throwback** button should display **unlike** and like Count should be 1100.
please Help how can i achieve this ?

[image]
[image]

//DetailOfUser.m

```
    #impot"DetailsOfStories.h"    
    @interface DetailOfUser ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
    {
      NSMutableArray *arrayAboutList;
        DetailsOfStories *viewController;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UILabel *title=[(UILabel *)cell viewWithTag:2];
    title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayAboutList[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"]];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    viewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsOfStories"];
   viewController.descriptionList = [arrayAboutList[indexPath.row] mutableCopy];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];


}
@end
```

//DetailsOfStories.m

```
#import "DetailOfUser.h"
@interface DetailsOfStories ()
{
    NSMutableArray *descriptionList;
BOOL buttonToggled;
    int number,number1;
    NSNumber *num1;
}
@end
@implementation DetailsOfStories
@synthesize descriptionList;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   UILabel *like_count=(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    NSNumber *someNumber = @(number);
    NSString *someString = [someNumber stringValue];
    like_count.text=someString;
}
- (IBAction)like:(id)sender {

    if (!buttonToggled) {
        [sender setTitle:@"Unlike" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //number is interger
        number = [num1 intValue]+1;
        number1=number;
        UILabel *like_count=(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
        NSNumber *someNumber = @(number);
        NSString *someString = [someNumber stringValue];
        like_count.text=someString;
        buttonToggled = YES;
    }
    else {
        [sender setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        number1 = number1-1;
        UILabel *like_count=(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
        NSNumber *someNumber = @(number1);
        NSString *someString = [someNumber stringValue];
        like_count.text=someString;
        buttonToggled = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the 'likes' number and status into a data model.
Both your controllers can access and modify the data model. In this case, data model can be a `singleton`, so that you can acquire it in your controllers.
May be you need sync data to server or persistent data to local storage later, data model can encapsulate all this service.

Here is some code sample

```
// YourDataModel
@interface YourDataModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *numbersOfLike;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL like;

@end
@implemention 
+ (id)shareInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  static YourDataModel *model;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
     model = [[YourDataModel alloc] init];
  });
  return model;
}

// maybe sync data to backend server.
- (void)sync {
}

// load like numbers from local storage or remote server
- (instancetype)init {

}

// Then you can use it in your controllers
[[YourDataModel shareInstance] like];
[[YourDataModel shareInstance] numbersOfLike];
[[YourDataModel shareInstance] setLike:false];
```

Update:

If you want to update your story viewcontroller back from detail page. You can update 'like status' in its `viewWillAppear()` delegate. You can check details on [Apple's official document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434415-viewwillappear?language=objc).

Comment: Good idea, but an inappropriate model.  The OP needs a model that has an array of stories, the stories have attributes like title, text, likeCount, etc.  It also must provide some way to determine that this user liked the story.  That probably indicates that there's a user object in the model.  That bigger model (a user and a storyList) would be the thing that's a singleton in this case.

Comment: @danh Yes, you are right. Like or not is a user status, the model should be designed according to OP's real scenario ;).

Comment: @Nickolas can i try saving the data in json file because all thease like counts are getting extracted from my .json file so if I can write the data back to json file it can really help ??

Comment: @HarshitGoel Yes, you can store data to JSON file. If the data is small, JSON file is a good choice. If the data is large enough, there is possible performance issue. Cause JSON is non-structured data, so you must write/read the whole JSON every time. In that situation, you may consider using database eg. [core data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html).

Comment: @Nickolas okay thanks nick sir even though the issue has been fully resolved. but I still want you to please write the code of adding data in a .json format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641672/saving-data-in-nsdictionary-from-nsdictionary?noredirect=1&lq=1 an example of json file

Comment: @Nickolas i know how to read it but write dont know so please help ?

Comment: @Goel You can use `NSData`. First, convert your JSON string to `NSData` with specific encoding, mostly UTF8. like  `NSData* data = [yourJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`. And then, save NSData to file. `[data writeToFile:yourFilePath atomically:YES];`. You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1408033-writetofile?language=objc).